# Syntax error, insert "while ( Expression ) ;" to complete DoStatement

Tags: java

Estoy realizando un sencillo juego BlackJack en JAVA Eclipse Neon. Se me presentó un problema al realizar este bucle, y la verdad no tengo idea cómo solucionarlo. Ya investigué, pero aún sigo con ese problema, espero alguien me pueda colaborar con ese `while` y el `do`.

```java
do{ // Open do
    System.out.println("¿Cuánto dinero desea apostar?");
    apuesta = entrada.nextInt();
    if (apuesta < 0 || apuesta > dinero) { // Open if
        System.out.println("Su apuesta debe ser mayor a 0 y menor a " + dinero + "pesos");
    } // Close if
} // close do
```

Comment: Por favor no pegues imágenes de tu editor de código. Incluye el código y darle formato al mismo pulsando control + k. Si en un futuro el servidor que aloja la imagen desapareciese o eliminase la misma tu código no podrá ser revisado por nadie en el futuro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error que el compilador genera es claro. En la línea 38 debes insertar un `while(condicion)` donde `condicion` es una expresión booleana que devuelve `true` o `false` mientras devuelva `true` hará que el bloque dentro de tu sentencia `do-while` se ejecute siempre.

Recuerda que la sintaxis de la sentencia `do-while` es la siguiente:

```
do {
//Bloque de código a ejecutar
//...
}while(condicion);
```